# Is there a way to use Keycloak Confidential authentication using Vue JS?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, keycloak

We are using Keycloak with Spring boot. We were using thymelaf earlier so Keycloak authentication mode was confidential (Using Client Id and Secret Key). Now we are planning to use vue js as a front end technology.
Is there a way we can use same authentication mode in Vue JS ?

Comment: May I ask why would you use confidential client instead of public one for frontend?

Comment: Typical usage here is a public client for frontend (there is no way to hide the secret), and a bearer-only client for the backend. There is no token-validation in the frontend, since security measures should not be placed where the user can see and control all the code and data.

Answer (score 0):

In Keycloak 8.0.1 you cannot use confidential client for Javascript adapter. See [Release Notes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#credentials-support-removed-from-the-javascript-adapter)

> Credentials support removed from the JavaScript adapter
>   The option to provide client credentials in the JavaScript adapter was removed. Thanks to jonkoops

Anyway you should not to as the client secret is publicly available.

Comment: that is sad. I was need to do that